# Create View in MySQL of only rows with a certain string in column

Tags: mysql

I'd like to create a database view and to have this view consist only of rows with a certain string in a specific column.

I know this doesn't work, but should give the general idea:

```
 create view education_level
SELECT * FROM `full_data` WHERE `category` contains 'Education Level'
```

What do I have to do in this example to create a view that contains only those rows that have "Education Level" as the value in the "Category" column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW education_level AS
SELECT * FROM `full_data` 
WHERE `category` like '%Education Level%';
```

Answer (score 1):

If the categorie is 'Education Level' use:

```
SELECT * FROM `full_data` WHERE category = 'Education Level'
```

If there might be something after Education Level, e.g. 'Education Level 2' use:

```
SELECT * FROM `full_data` WHERE category LIKE 'Education Level%'
```

If there might be something in front of Education Level, e.g. 'this Education Level' use:

```
SELECT * FROM `full_data` WHERE category LIKE '%Education Level'
```

If there might be something before AND after the Education Level, e.g. 'This Education Level 2' use:

```
SELECT * FROM `full_data` WHERE category = '%Education Level%'
```

Answer (score 0):

create view education_level
   SELECT * FROM `full_data` WHERE category = 'Education Level'

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 WHERE `category` LIKE 'Education Level'
```